# Removing OData schema from swagger. Asp.net Core Web Api 5.0

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger, odata, swagger-ui

How can I remove extra scheme objects that are being generated by OData from swagger asp.net core web api 5.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same situation and built the functionality into a framework I wrote.  The answer is that you need to create an IDocumentFilter.  Here's a sample based on .net 6:

https://github.com/ikemtz/NRSRx/blob/master/src/IkeMtz.NRSRx.Core.OData/ODataCommonDocumentFilter.cs

In your startup.cs do the following:

```
   .AddSwaggerGen(swaggerGenOptions =>
        {
          swaggerGenOptions.DocumentFilter<ODataCommonDocumentFilter>();
        });
```